# Linux Shell Script cut last part of variable which contains a path

Tags: linux, string, shell, sh

So long story short I have to make a Shell Script where I need to have something like two variables, the first one contains a path read from the keyboard (something like:`this/is/the/path/I/need`)

I really need to extract the last folder of that path example, and put it in another variable, in my example I need to get out of the path the "need" part and put it in the second variable. How can I do this? The fact that this is read from the keyboard makes it pretty hard to do in my opinion. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ read path
this/is/the/path/I/need
$ directory=$(basename $path)
$ echo $directory
need
$
```